# android virtual device - views got strange background colors

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am using the current Android SDK, r15.

In my Project, I am using ListViews with customized Adapters, based on BaseAdapter. In the BaseAdapter::getView-method, there is a view, inflated from xml ressources and customized and filled with text; also the background color is changed, depending on several conditions. This works great at all, but:

On Android Virtual Devices (AVD) with Android 3.0 and higher, I've got the problem, that at some point, when Android tries to recycle existing views, the background color does not change, even if it is specified in the xml ressource.

Shall I assume, that this is a problem of the android emulator, or may it be that this also happens on real devices?
I never saw this problem on a real device yet, with the same application.

non-abstracted example:
I've got a project with a login-layout (almost white, with input fields and a button), a "tablet"-layout containing a contact listView and a conversation listView; after logging in, I am able to select a contact. Online contacts have got a green background, offline contacts a white one. After selecting the contact the background of the contact turns red. Conversation is loaded into the conversation listView. Now I log off, and now it could be that my former white login is green or red, as in the contact ListView before. Also, it could be that even my conversation listView-Entries inherit the color of a contact listView element, ignoring the background color specified in the xml. That seems quite random.

Shortened code of getView:
(just excluded the code for setting 'profileImage')

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_listelement, parent, false);

        int userId = contactList.get(position);
        BackendStamp user = users.get(userId);

        ImageView profileImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
        TextView username = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.username);
        TextView unreadMails = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.unreadMails);
        ImageView userStatus = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.userStatus);

        if (user != null) {

            if (user.getUnreadMails() == 0) {
                unreadMails.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgmessagesnull);
                unreadMails.setTextColor(0xff000000);
            }
            else {
                unreadMails.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgmessagesnotnull);
                unreadMails.setTextColor(0xffffffff);
            }

            if (user.getStatus() == 0) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            }
            else {
                view.setBackgroundColor(0xFFEFFFD4);
            }

// [...]

            username.setText(user.getNickname());
            unreadMails.setText("" + user.getUnreadMails());

// [...]            

        }

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Can you put the code for `getView` function?

Comment: I'd edited the question, now including the code of `getView`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    if(convertView == null) {
      view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_listelement, parent, false);
    }
    else {
      view = convertView;
    }
```

Even if this does not solve your problem, this is great performance boost to your `ListView`. As Android tries to re-use views, `convertView` is `null` first time and then it contains the old created views which are re-cycled and should be used.

Comment: Thanks for this improvement :)

Comment: Nope. The views with corrupt background colors are getting loaded on a different locations via setContentView(R.layout.[...]);

Comment: I'd fixed the issue with the following solution:
Now I am using different layouts which are precoloured, means, I don't change the background color manually. This fixes the issue.

Comment: I am confused now. So corrupted views are not just in `getView` but somewhere else also? And you expect changes to views in `getView` will reflect at that place also?

Comment: In the contact listview, everything goes right. But in the conversation listview and on other views, the android:background-Attribute gets overwritten by the view.setBackgroundColor-method when android recycles the view. That's all about this.